# Plot line graph on top of line graph at scale when numbers are different

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot two line graphs on top of each other, but at a scale where they both can be seen. Currently I am doing something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_1 = [1, 10, 30, 4, 50]

data_2 = [1000, 1020, 1050, 1300]

plt.plot(data_1)
plt.plot(data_2)

plt.show()
```

But this results in

[image]

What I want is the plots to be on top of each other, each with its own axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use separate Y axis for each line with `ax.twinx`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_1 = [1, 10, 30, 4, 50]
data_2 = [1000, 1020, 1050, 1300]

# Get Axes instances
fig, ax_left = plt.subplots()
ax_right = ax_left.twinx()

# Left Y axis
ax_left.plot(data_1, color='red', label='Data 1')
ax_left.set_ylabel('Data 1')
ax_left.legend()

# Right Y axis
ax_right.plot(data_2, color='orange', label='Data 2')
ax_right.set_ylabel('Data 2')
ax_right.legend()

plt.show()
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. How do I set the X label?

Comment: Use `set_xlabel` method from `ax_right` or `ax_left` (either will do).